# Hide "/angular/" in URL and use .htaccess to rewrite if the URL has a fragment identifier (#)

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, angular.js

I have site setup in `wordpress` as root folder like `/wordpress` and one `angular` site setup in sub folder `/wordpress/angular`.

Currently if user visits `url` like `example.com/wordpress/sample-page`, it displays `wp` page and if visits like  `example.com/wordpress/angular/#/sample-page` or `example.com/wordpress/angular/#/parent-page/child-page`, it displays `angular` page.

After `#/`, whatever it is, it should stay on angular page. Currently it is staying, but `angular` in URL should not be shown

**I want to remove `angular` from `url` if user visits `angular` page.**

So, I put `.htaccess` file in `wordpress` folder like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)angular
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ angular/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now if I visit a URL like `example.com/wordpress/#/any-url`, it should stay on `angular`' page but not working.

I guess I need to check if url contains `#`, then make it redirect to `angular` folder. As it is a `special character`, how to make some condition on above code.

I am taking ref from

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795134/htaccess-rewrite-url-remove-subdirectory

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220377/htaccess-redirect-if-url-contains-a-certain-string

I am not much expert on `htaccess` config. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't check for `#` in *.htaccess*.   The fragment identifier (after the `#`) is client side only.  It is never sent to the server.  Only your JavaScript can see it.

Comment: any other way around to hide `angular` from `url` ?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that exactly what you want to accomplish is not possible.
Here is some useful information for you.

First off:
`#` and whatever comes after is never sent to the web server, and therefore .htaccess doesn't have access to read it.
`#` is only used by the client (the web browser), whatever comes after it can be read by the browser and javascript however.

If you still want the wordpress site under /wordpress/ to work normally, you CAN NOT .htaccess rewrite `/wordpress/#/sample-page` URLs to show content as if the user visited `/wordpress/angular/#/sample-page`

If you want to "hide" `angular/` for the user when the user is at the url, that is best done with javascript.
If this is for SEO purpose, google would still see and index the /angular/ url, if you don't want that, you would have to come up with some completely other solution.